# While booting from USB, after clicking "Try Ubuntu", computer freezes

Tags: boot, system-installation, usb, live-usb

I have attempted to make a bootable USB for Ubuntu 13.04 (ubuntu-13.04-desktop-1386). I used the Pendrivelinux  Universal USB Installer program in order to make it bootable.

The problem comes after I boot my PC (Windows XP Home),  tap <kbd>F11</kbd> to choose to boot from USB, the OS loads up, and gives me the option to either try and install.

When I press "Try Ubuntu" the screen flashes black, then loads up a background, a cursor, and nothing else.

How can I resolve this issue?

The USB is formatted NTFS and is 32GB.

Comment: Try formatting the drive as `Fat32`

Comment: First, format the drive to FAT32. Then follow the instructions given [here](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows). If the USB is still faulty, you should consider downloading the ISO again. Try using BitTorrent (with uTorrent for example), the link for the torrent file is [this](http://releases.ubuntu.com/13.04/ubuntu-13.04-desktop-i386.iso.torrent).

Comment: Regarding formatting that USB to FAT32, I had tried that previously however I was greeted with the error of "No default ui or configuration directive found". Renaming 'iso' to 'sys' didn't do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

It could be a problem with your graphics card, because Ubuntu uses those new open source drivers.

Edit the startup options on "Try Ubuntu" (If you use UnetBootin first highlight "try ubuntu", then press tab (or was it e?). On pendrivelinux I'm not sure where you can edit those). And insert `nomodeset` next to the other boot options. Then boot with this option.

It should boot up successfully if the graphic driver was the problem. You then have to install the proprietary drivers (after Ubuntu installation).

Comment: I see. My desktop is quite old...correction, it is very old. Graphics drivers do seem like a probable issue.

I shall try use UnetBootin, and will inform you of the results promptly. Thank you :)

Comment: I just downloaded UNetbootin, however, I'm a bit confused on what you mean by _first highlight "try ubuntu"_?

Just in case I wasn't clear, the screen after which Ubuntu hangs is [this](http://assets.ubuntu.com/sites/ubuntu/latest/u/img/download/desktop-install-1.png).

PS: I can't seem to embed a picture here :\

Comment: @Red Yes, I also thought that it would hang there. By highlight I mean, select the option Try Ubuntu (but don't press enter, press the edit key TAB). Then you can edit the command line, just insert `nomodeset` to the other options (like splash etc.). Then press enter.